# Duvida quanto ao selenium e python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo um bot para o instagram, chega determinada parte da página que eu tenho uma lista de pessoas com o botão "seguir" do lado.

fiz esse código:

```
bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/people/suggested/')
        time.sleep(3)
        for i in range(1, 30):
            time.sleep(5)
            seguir = bot.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
            seguir.click()
            time.sleep(5)
            bot.refresh()
```

A cada click do botão "seguir", o bot da um refresh na página, quem ele seguiu some da página e quem está em 2 lugar sobe para 1 e assim o bot clica novamente.
O problema é que quando chega na 5 ou 7 pessoa, o botão buga, ele não clica mais e entra em loop.
**Segue abaixo a imagem da lista que recebo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teria como contornar esse problema?

Comment: qual o erro que retorna?

Comment: nenhum. esse é o problema, quando chega na 7 ou 9 pessoa, ele começa a clicar, dar o refresh e quando a página recarrega a mesma pessoa ainda continua lá, como se não tivesse sido seguida, e então começa a ficar nesse loop.

Comment: existe o método `find_elements_by_tag` que retorna uma `array` dos elementos e da pra iteira eles em um `for`